# Am I required to update the procfile if I add new files?

Tags: git, github, heroku, github-desktop

I have an app that I inherited and I just added a new shell script at the root level. I added it and pushed it onto my app on Heroku, but I keep getting permission errors that it's not executeable on Heroku's logs. Exact error is: `bash: ./release.sh: Permission denied`

I just discovered the `procfile` but am confused if I need to update it to reflect this new file and how to update it. I tried adding the following line: `release: chmod a+x release.sh && ./release.sh` but that threw errors. I know this question is fundamentally update file permissions, but I think it's more of a prcofile-related question. So assuming that I need to update the procfile, how do I properly update it to change file permissions and run the shell script?

Comment: What is the exact error you’re getting? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder - added that detail in

Comment: git clone your project, chmod a+x the file and git commit the file to your project.

Comment: Thanks - I'm on Windows and was able to get around the restraint using Git Bash

Comment: Nevermind, I'm still having trouble executing the script. It seems like making any changes locally doesn't get 'saved' on Heroku